# How to access HTML5 localstorage in Rails View Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, local-storage

I have saved some keys in html5 localstorage using JavaScript running on my views:

```
<script>
function setKeys()
{
 localstorage.setItem("key","some_value")
}
</script>
```

Now I want to access these values in one of my Rails controllers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: that was rude..anyway thanks for link.. i am new to Rails/Web Programming, what i m guessing is localstorage is on client side and if i have to access it in my controller, i should sent to rails app by some means, may be below answer by user2564200 points me in right direction(by using some ajax request)

Answer (score 4):

You will have to send it to the controller via an AJAX request or something.

```
value = localstorage.getItem("key")
jQuery.ajax(some_url, { data: { key: value } })
```